# Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that $e^{(x+1)} \geq 2e^x$

Tags: real-analysis

Use the Mean Value Theorem to show that
$e^{x+1}\geq 2e^x, \space\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$.

A hint that was given was: Consider the interval $[x,x+1].$

Can someone show me a step by step proof?

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

> $$ \frac{e^{x+1}-e^x}{(x+1)-x}=e^{\eta} \quad \eta \in (x,x+1). $$

Comment: No doubt this is what the teacher intended...

Comment: Presumably this also needs the derivative of $e^x$ being $e^x$

Answer (score 2):

Divide across by $e^x$ to get $e \ge 2$. Since $e^x \ge 1+x$ for $x \ge 0$, we have $e \ge 1+1 = 2$, as required.

Here is another way:
Let $f(x) = e^{x+1}-2 e^x$. Now note that $\log:(0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a bijection, so we can just check if $f(\log t) \ge 0$ for all $t \ge 0$. Since $f(\log t) = (e-2)t$, we see the problem comes back to showing $e \ge 2$ again.

Comment: Definitely the sane way to do it.

Comment: It says use the Mean Value Theorem. Without the Mean Value Theorem you are overkilling... $e^{(x+1)}=ee^x\geq 2e^x$ $\bullet$

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: I am sure Mhenni's solution is the intended one.

Answer (score 2):

Going from the hint, MVT between $x,x+1$ on $e^{x+1}$ gives

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ $\exists c\in(x,x+1),$ $e^{x+2}-e^{x+1}=e^{c+1}(x+1-x)$

Cleaing up a little:

$e^{x+1}-e^{x}=e^{c}$

$e^{x+1}=e^{c}+e^{x}$

Add $0 = e^x - e^x$ to get the $2e^x$ you were looking for on the RHS

$e^{x+1}=2e^{x}+(e^c-e^x)$

Finally since $c\in(x,x+1)$ and $e^x$ is strictly increasing $e^c > e^x$ and $e^c-e^x$ is positive, so that for all $x\in\mathbb{R},$ $e^{x+1}>2e^x$